# How to find co-ordinates from google map api to display markers from database in map

Tags: api

I have a search page in which I am displaying properties from my database as markers in google map. Now I want to modify this search page so that any user will draw either a circle or polygon in the google map and will get properties from our database only in the selected area (drawn by user itself). I am attaching my code so far here.

The circle in the image shows the selected area and the result must display properties available in the selected region. My table contains 2 different fields for latitude and longitude of each property.

**Javascript code:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var drawingManager;
    var all_overlays = [];
    var selectedShape;
    var colors = ['#1E90FF', '#FF1493', '#32CD32', '#FF8C00', '#4B0082'];
    var selectedColor;
    var colorButtons = {};

    function clearSelection() {
        if (selectedShape) {
            selectedShape.setEditable(false);
            selectedShape = null;
        }
    }

    function setSelection(shape) {
        clearSelection();
        selectedShape = shape;
        shape.setEditable(true);
        selectColor(shape.get('fillColor') || shape.get('strokeColor'));
    }

    function deleteSelectedShape() {
        if (selectedShape) {
            selectedShape.setMap(null);
        }
    }

    function deleteAllShape() {
        for (var i = 0; i < all_overlays.length; i++) {
            all_overlays[i].overlay.setMap(null);
        }
        all_overlays = [];
    }

    function selectColor(color) {
        selectedColor = color;
        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
            var currColor = colors[i];
            colorButtons[currColor].style.border = currColor == color ? '2px solid #789' : '2px solid #fff';
        }

        // Retrieves the current options from the drawing manager and replaces the
        // stroke or fill color as appropriate.
        var polylineOptions = drawingManager.get('polylineOptions');
        polylineOptions.strokeColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('polylineOptions', polylineOptions);

        var rectangleOptions = drawingManager.get('rectangleOptions');
        rectangleOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('rectangleOptions', rectangleOptions);

        var circleOptions = drawingManager.get('circleOptions');
        circleOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('circleOptions', circleOptions);

        var polygonOptions = drawingManager.get('polygonOptions');
        polygonOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('polygonOptions', polygonOptions);
    }

    function setSelectedShapeColor(color) {
        if (selectedShape) {
            if (selectedShape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
                selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
            } else {
                selectedShape.set('fillColor', color);
            }
        }
    }

    function makeColorButton(color) {
        var button = document.createElement('span');
        button.className = 'color-button';
        button.style.backgroundColor = color;
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function () {
            selectColor(color);
            setSelectedShapeColor(color);
        });

        return button;
    }

    function buildColorPalette() {
        var colorPalette = document.getElementById('color-palette');
        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
            var currColor = colors[i];
            var colorButton = makeColorButton(currColor);
            colorPalette.appendChild(colorButton);
            colorButtons[currColor] = colorButton;
        }
        selectColor(colors[0]);
    }

    function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 6,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(22, 77),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoomControl: true
        });

        var polyOptions = {
            strokeWeight: 0,
            fillOpacity: 0.45,
            editable: true
        };
        // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
        // markers, lines, and shapes.
        drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            markerOptions: {
                draggable: true
            },
            polylineOptions: {
                editable: true
            },
            rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
            circleOptions: polyOptions,
            polygonOptions: polyOptions,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (e) {
            all_overlays.push(e);
            if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
                // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
                drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

                // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
                // mouses down on it.
                var newShape = e.overlay;
                newShape.type = e.type;
                google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function () {
                    setSelection(newShape);
                });
                setSelection(newShape);
            }
        });

        // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
        // map is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-all-button'), 'click', deleteAllShape);

        buildColorPalette();
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

The code above contains some events to handle the user interaction in search page to draw cirle,polygone to search property in selected region.

The display property button in the image must show property markers in the selected area.

How would I get the latitude and longitude of selected area of circle or polygon?
How Would I query my database for that range of co-ordinates?

Thanking you very much in advance for your kind help...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have found a solution since you post this question.
However, if someone else needs an answer, this is how you can get lat / lng of a drawing polygon :

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
    var polygonBounds = polygon.getPath();
}
```

The bounds of each vertices of your polygon are now in `polygonBounds`, just iterate over it and do what you want with lat / lng

For a circle, you just need lat / lng of the center, and its radius

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function(circle) {
        var radius = circle.getRadius();
        var center = circle.getCenter();
}
```

Hope it can help someone

PS : I'm using GoogleMaps v3.14, I never test with other versions.